# Implicit conversion loses integer precision: warning, code for 64-bit platform

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, nsinteger

after getting a lot of warnings when changing (by accident) the simulator (from 32 to 64 bit platforms), I'm getting rid of all the `int` declaration and changing those for `NSinteger`s.

But I have another warning in this piece of code:

```
- (IBAction)nextText:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    NSInteger i=[self.indexPathArray indexOfObject:[self indexPathForActiveText]];
    //before it was int i=... 

    if (i<[self.indexPathArray count]-1) {

        [self moveRows:++i];
    }
}
```

however on the line `[self moveRows:++i];` I get this warning again:

> 'implicit conversion loses integer precision:...'

Comment: show `moveRows:` declaration or definition...

Comment: There's a hidden bug in your condition `i < [self.indexPathArray count] - 1` (for an empty `indexPathArray`). Change it to `i + 1 < [self.indexPathArray count]`.

Comment: Good call, thanks. I made sure in my implementation that the array is never empty, but one is never too sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should show warning in 64-bit platform. `NSInteger i=[self.indexPathArray indexOfObject:[self indexPathForActiveText]];` Because `indexOfObject:` return `NSUInteger.` So your code should be as below

```
NSUInteger i=[self.indexPathArray indexOfObject:[self indexPathForActiveText]];
```

And also

```
-(void)moveRows:(NSUInteger)index;
```

[See this apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html)

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!! I'm getting acquaintance with the whole thing, after a long pause on programming. Thanks again!